# How to limit generic type to a map whose key is picked from props in values?

Tags: typescript

I want to find a type of map with keys eq to its values' properties like:

```
type IndexMap<I extends keyof V, V extends { [K in I]: string }> = {
  [P in V[I]]: V
}

const test: IndexMap<'prop', { ok: number, prop: string }> = {
  someVal: {
    ok: 1,
    prop: 'someVal' // Currently, can be violated without compile error.
  }
}
```

Then, I can use it in generic constraint like:

```
class Service<T extends IndexMap<'name', CustomizedPreDefinedApiModel>> {
  // T is limited to IndexMap. Can be used to type check in service methods.
}
```

Any way to implement it?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the result type - `type A = IndexMap<'prop', { ok: number, prop: string }>`. Can you write what the result type A should be?

Comment: @Maciej Sikora For such a type A. It's ok for ```const a: A = { data: { ok: 1, prop: 'data' }}```. But not ```const error: A = {some: { ok: 1, prop: 'data' }}```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type definition is fully fine, but we need to understand the difference between type level and value level in TS. Consider:

```
type TypeA = IndexMap<'prop', { ok: number, prop: string }>
// is evaluated to:
type TypeA = {
    [x: string]: {
        ok: number;
        prop: string;
    };
}
```

Pay attention that our key `x` equals in type to `prop` key value type. So everything is correct in type level. We declare that `prop: string` and compilator indeed watch over that. So putting for example number into prop will show compilation error.

Yes but this is not what we want here, but defined type of variable doesn't do any inferation over the values. Consider:

```
const test: IndexMap<'prop', { ok: number, prop: string }> = {
  someVal: {
    ok: 1,
    prop: 'someVal' // Currently, can be violated without compile error.
  }
}
```

We define statically the type, we say prop is a string, so the value on the right is indeed valid member of this type. But there is no way to change this type by the value. The only way to infer type arguments is by function arguments, I will get back to that shortly.

If we will use more strict type, the result will be different.

```
type TypeB = IndexMap<'prop', { ok: number, prop: 'val'}>;
// it evaluates into
type TypeB = {
    val: { // correctly narrowed key
        ok: number;
        prop: "val"; // correctly narrowed type
    };
}
```

So, the original type works as expected, as you give it a prop type, and it creates wanted structure. But how to connect value level with type level in order to not put such specific types, I assume that this is what you want.

First of all small changes in your type:

```
type IndexMap<I extends keyof V, V extends { [K in I]: PropertyKey }> = {
  [P in V[I]]: V
}
```

I changed string in `PropertyKey`, this type says that we need to have at given key `I` value which can be used as key (string | number | symbol).

Now how to make values which are proper for the given type, without specifying the type directly. We can make value constructor function. Consider:

```
const makeTest = <I extends keyof V, V extends { [K in I]: VK }, VK extends PropertyKey>(a:I, b:V) => {
  return {
    [b[a]]: {
      ...b
    }
  } as IndexMap<I, V>
}
const test3 = makeTest('a', { 'a': 'value', b: 1 });
const test4 = makeTest('b', { 'a': 'value', b: 1 });
```

Both `test3` and `test4` are proper values of `IndexMap` type. We don't need to define explicitly the type, as we can derive it from arguments, also type is specified and narrowed properly.

---

To sum it up. When saying something has given type like `a: T`, we are constraining value `a` to type `T`, but what we put in the value `a` will not impact type `T`.

Comment: So, there is no way to declare the constraint without using function?

Comment: If you want value level to impact type level then yes it's the only way.